# Need to create FUNSD dataset using Label studio

Tags: pdf, nlp, annotations, label, ocr

Is there any way we can create the FUNSD dataset using LabelStudio?

1. I have taken my pdf
2. Perform OCR on that using pytessseract

But I am not sure what kind of post preprocessing needs to be done on the JSON file in order to use it as a FUNSD dataset for LayoutLMV1

Comment: Hey did you find any way to annotate the documents, in the FUNSD way?